# How to create a selector to affine view (like a filter) through rest api

Tags: angular, rest, angular6

I need to do a selector with all the continents of the world. If a user click in a continent the view have to show only the countries of that continent.

I'm getting the countries on https://restcountries.eu.

```html
<h2>Countries</h2>
<div >
  <nav class="navbar">
    <input class="form-control shadow-sm p-3 mb-5 bg-white rounded" type="text" name="search" [(ngModel)]="filter">

  <select id="region" class="shadow-sm p-3 mb-5 bg-white rounded">
      <option value=""></option>
      <option value="afr" routerLink="/region/africa">Africa</option>
      <option value="ame">Americas</option>
      <option value="asi">Asia</option>
      <option value="eur">Europe</option>
      <option value="oce">Oceania</option>
  </select>
</nav>

  <tr *ngFor="let country of countries | filter:filter; let i = index">
      <td>{{country.name}}</td>
      <td>{{country.population}}</td>
      <td>{{country.region}}</td>
      <td>{{country.capital}}</td>
  </tr>
</div>
```

Comment: Not clear what your question is, is the code not doing what you expect? Are you looking for specific advice? please give these details before we can reasonably help you.

Comment: I dont Know what to do to filter my results after the continent selection

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood what you are trying to do, you should do somethin like this:

```
  <select id="region" class="shadow-sm p-3 mb-5 bg-white rounded" (change)='yourFilterFunction($event)>
```

Where the "yourFilterFunction($event)" updates the countries array

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, you should iterate over the already filtered countries according to the applied filter.

1. The user selects the filter
2. Filter countries according to the selected continent
3. Display filtered countries